# JQM jump to previous page after clicking link

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using prestashop (1.4), I've installed 'mobile theme' module (for mobile client) which uses jqm (1.3.2) on top of jquery (1.9.1)

If I go to a page and as soon as the page displayed **but before the page is fully loaded** , I click on a link, the new page is displayed and then after a few second the previous page is displayed.

I think that when JQM finished to load the previous page it's call some handler that cause it to display.

I solve it by changing the JQM code (line 5021, http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js) so that it will display any link as an external link.

but I would like to know if I can fix it without changing the JQM code

Comment: 1) How long is it taking to load? 2) Feel like disabling links until the page is fully loaded?

Comment: The page show after some second but it loads imgs of hidden menu for a few more second, disabling links for that long is not reasonable